# Does a es6 js export have to export a function?

Tags: javascript, class, import, ecmascript-6

I want to use the `import` keyword in a class. The data to import would be a simple object eg:

```
{
   test: 123,
   anothertest: 321
}
```

I know i can write:

```
module.exports = {
  test: 123,
  anothertest: 321
}
```

And then in the class i can just require the module

```
let data = require('./modulename')
```

But how can i just write a simple export so in the class i can just write

```
import data from 'modulename'
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import demonstrates how to do this with a function but not a simple object.

Comment: Why have you not seen [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)?

Comment: :) what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
const data = {
    test: 123,
    anothertest: 321
};

export default data;
```

If you have more stuff to export, then you could export it like this:

```
const data = {
     test: 123,
     anothertest: 321
};

const stuff = {
     test: 464,
     another: 323
};

export { data, stuff };
```

And then you can import it like this:

```
import { data, stuff } from './file';
```